# Line won't draw on an image using ImageDraw

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, python-imaging-library, draw

I am trying to use PIL to open an image, then draw a line on it, but it is not working. I am trying to make a leveling display, with the line being how far the user has leveled up.

I've tried creating a new image using `Image.new`, and having a base already available and opening it using `Image.open`, and I've also tried putting the coordinates directly into the function, and just putting the two-tuples as variables and calling those variables into the function (as seen below). The base image is a transparent image.

```py
    length = 300 # Used as a placeholder integer, as this would change depending on user's level
    base = Image.open('./level_up/base.png')
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(base)
    pos1 = (280, 324)
    pos2 = (280, length + 324)
    draw.line((pos1, pos2), fill=(255, 102, 168), width=20)
    base.save('./level_up/base2.png')
```

I open up the image, which is a blank, transparent image that is `1500 x 296`, and nothing is there. No line or anything.

Comment: Try changing `base = Image.open('./level_up/base.png')` to `base = Image.open('./level_up/base.png').convert('RGB')`

Comment: that will show the line, but also will also destructively modify all transparent areas in the image.

Comment: Kindly share your input image so we can see what's going on. Thank you.

Comment: @jsbueno I assume the input image doesn't have transparency because OP draws line with only RGB and no A component. Though I may be wrong so I have requested OP share image :-)

Answer (score 1):

As you are working with an image containing transparency (mode "RGBA" in PIL), you have to explicitly pass an opacity as the 4th component of colors.
Just add "255", meaning 100% opacity to the fill color in your call for line, and it should work:

```
draw.line((pos1, pos2), fill=(255, 102, 168, 255), width=20)
```

Comment: That still didn't work, the image output still is a blank, transparent ``1500 x 296`` image, with no markup on it.

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out, I should have reversed the coordinates for the ``pos1`` and ``pos2`` two-tuples, because the Y-coordinate was off the screen. Once I reversed them it finally showed up, but thanks anyways!